# Get price necessary for stock to cross up or down

Tags: pine-script

Using pine script is it possible to get the price necessary to have the stochastic indicator cross up or down?

I have the following at the moment which displays a basic stochastic. I can identify when a cross over or cross under (using `ta.crossover`) occurs however I want to know ahead of time what price the current bar needs to close at in order for the stochastic to change direction.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Stochastic with crossover detail")

periodK = input.int(14, title="K", minval=1)
periodD = input.int(3, title="D", minval=1)
smoothK = input.int(3, title="Smooth", minval=1)

k = ta.stoch(close, high, low, periodK)
d = ta.sma(k, periodD)

plot(k, title = "%K", color = color.blue)
plot(d, title = "%D", color = color.orange)

h0 = hline(80, "Upper Band", color = color.white)
h1 = hline(20, "Lower Band", color = color.white)
fill(h0, h1, color=color.rgb(33,150,243,90), title = "Background")

direction = ta.rising(periodK, periodD) //Intenting to use this to get the current stoch direction

hline_price_1 = 100 //I want this value to be the price the current bar needs to close at for the stoch to run in the other direction.
label hline_label_1 = label.new(bar_index + 10, hline_price_1, str.tostring(hline_price_1), style=label.style_label_center, textcolor=color.white, color = color.gray, size = size.small)
label.set_y(hline_label_1, 50)
label.delete(hline_label_1[1])
```

Comment: Do you want to know in advance at what price the current bar will close? :)

Comment: I mean if we could just write a method that would predict the future that would be great!

Comment: On a more serious note though I mean if the price is currently $100 and the stoch is pointing down what price would it need to close at to turn it back up?